# retrieve imap emails from specific sender

Tags: vb.net, parsing, email, vb6

I am trying to convert something I wrote in outlook's vb editor into vb6, so that it can be a standalone executable.

What it does is:

1. parses a specific url from newly arrived emails from a specific sender. The url points to a webpage.Let's call it URL1
2. retrieves html content of that webpage and parses another url from within the html content. Let's call it URL2
3. downloads pdf from URL2.

So, in the outlook vb environment it's completely functional. But, since, I am leaving outlook I need to replace some code, specifically:

1. how do I retrieve e-mails (imap) from a specific sender? now that I cant use "Outlook.Items", ".HTMLBody," etc. or anything related to outlook.
2. get the html of the e-mail into my html parser
3. How do I restrict the program to doing this to only new e-mails and not ones that it has already parsed?

Basically, this is the code in pertinent part:

```
strURL1 = GetBetween(1, itm.HTMLBody, "<a href=""https://", """>", vbTextCompare)

Private Function GetBetween(ByVal Start As Long, Data As String, _
StartString As String, EndString As String, _
Optional ByVal CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As String

Dim lonStart As Long, lonEnd As Long

'1. Find start string.
lonStart = InStr(Start, Data, StartString, CompareMethod)

If lonStart > 0 Then
    '2. Move to end of start string.
    lonStart = lonStart + Len(StartString)

    '3. Find end string.
    lonEnd = InStr(lonStart, Data, EndString, CompareMethod)

    If lonEnd > 0 Then
        '4. Extract data between start and end strings.
        GetBetween = Mid$(Data, lonStart, lonEnd - lonStart)
    End If
End If
```

End Function

-------------------------below is some code that I will have to eliminate, I'm new to this and I am not sure exactly what they did, and if I will need a substitute for vb6?-----

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub


    Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

        If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
            Set Msg = item
            LaunchURL (item)
        End If

    ProgramExit:
      Exit Sub
    ErrorHandler:
      MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
      Resume ProgramExit

End Sub


Private WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to obtain these from an IMAP server without parasitizing Outlook you will need to find an IMAP ActiveX library.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention yes I want to hit imap server (gmail). I did a bit more research seems like I would have to pay for a custom library for imap funcationality. Is there a free resource for VB.net? I'm not familiar with it but from the looks of it, it looks just like the stuff I do in outlooks vb editor. But, can I still make it a standalone program?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of Exchange you are interested in so...

I have some VB6 code that connects to Exchange 2003 and reads a mail box. It uses the CDO 1.21 library (http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=3671). I have a reference to '\Program Files\ExchangeMapi\cdo.dll' in my project. I then use code like:

```
Dim s As mapi.Session
Dim Inbox As mapi.Folder
Dim Msgs As mapi.Messages
Dim Msg As mapi.Message
Dim Sender As AddressEntry
Dim i as Integer
Dim txt as String
Set s = CreateObject("MAPI.Session")
s.Logon "", "", False, True, 0, True, ServerName & vbLf & AccountName
Set Inbox = s.Inbox
Set Msgs = Inbox.Messages
For i = 1 To Msgs.Count
    Set Msg = Msgs.Item(i)
    Set Sender = Msg.Sender
    txt = Msg.Text
Next i
```

I run this in an XP VM for reasons I don't 100% recall but it may be that CDO and Windows 7 don't like each other.  As I recall there may be problems getting HTML bodies from emails. I am sorry I cannot be more specific - it is a long time since it was written (although it does still run).

CDO reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526914%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx

Comment: Looks like he wants to hit an IMAP server, not Exchange.

Comment: Yes, Imap, specifically gmail

Comment: ah I see. If you are moving completely away you might be better rewriting it: http://www.example-code.com/vb/imapReadFlags.asp